# managing public and private information of entities in session beans?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, ejb, entity

I see a lot of examples where entity objects are returned or passed in session bean methods. But the concept of remote interfaces for session beans make me think that this is bad practice as the entity might hold private data. A client doing remote calls to a session bean shouldn't be able to access all data. I'm just confused? If not, how should I encounter this issue? Should I create classes shadowing the entities public properties?

Let's say I have an entity class for users as following:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    ...
}
```

For visitors using a java client accessing this entity through a session bean, I want only the ***id*** and the ***username*** be visible for them. The authenticated user should be able to access all properties expect the ***password*** property. Isn't unsafe to have a session bean like this:

```
@Stateless
public class UserManager {
      public User getUserById(Integer id) {
            ...
      }
      public List<User> findUsers(String searchKey) {
            ...
      }

}
```

How should one encounter such security problems?

Comment: If the session bean is remote, and if untrusted clients are allowed to access it, then yes, it's a security (or privacy) problem. But most of the time, session beans are not remote, and even when they are, they're not accessible by untrusted clients.

Comment: ok thanks, that clears it up. Is there some mechanism in javaee to only allow connection from trusted clients when using remote? Or is it something that should be implemented in the beans?

Comment: That is something that should be implemented at the network infrastructure level. The machines in your LAN shouldn't be exposed to the outside world.